# Azure ActiveDirectory: How many groups max?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

This is a two part question.

1. What is the maximum number of Azure AD groups you can create?
2. Is there a best practice? We have over 3000 groups, and I’m wondering if it’s slowing things down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the maximum number of Azure AD groups you can create?

There is no specific limit about the number of groups. But there are limits about objects(include groups). A maximum of 50,000 objects can be created in a single directory by users of the Free edition of Azure Active Directory by default. See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-service-limits-restrictions).

> Is there a best practice? We have over 3000 groups, and I’m wondering
>   if it’s slowing things down.

The official documentation does not say that this number will affect performance. And I haven't seen any feedback about this.