# Quota of AAD Groups

Tags: azure-active-directory

I understand there is quota on the number of AAD Groups, it seems that it’s 250 as default.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-service-limits-restrictions
--> A user can create a maximum of 250 groups in an Azure AD organization.

And I believe this number can be increased by “Increase request” on portal.

[Resolve errors for resource quotas]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-resource-quota

My question is, how much number can AAD groups currently be increased as maximum.
As an instance, is it possible to increase maximum number of AAD groups to 1000?

Your help is highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no specific limit about the number of groups. The official document you provided just says one user can create maximum of 250 groups in Azure AD organization. So I think there is no problem if you want to create 1000 groups(with multiple users).

Here is a stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510304/azure-activedirectory-how-many-groups-max) which is related to your question, in this post the OP create 3000 groups.